# I am trying to build 8 x 8 grid its working but the problem is first line start from only one # sign

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to build 8 x 8 grid its working but the problem is first line start from only one # sign

```
function print(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
  return msg;
}


let result = "";

for(let i=1; i<=8; i++) {
    result += " #\n"
    for(let j=1; j<8; j++) {
        result += " #";
    }
}

print(result);
// output is
#
 # # # # # # # #
 # # # # # # # #
 # # # # # # # #
 # # # # # # # #
 # # # # # # # #
 # # # # # # # #
 # # # # # # # #
 # # # # # # #
```

I am trying to build 8 x 8 grid its working but the problem is first line start from only one # sign

Comment: What do you think about that? Read your script slowly and think about where to add `\n`.

Comment: You are close, just create nested loops, where inner will print `#`, and outer will print only `\n`. And always start loops from 0, future you will thank for that.

Comment: Here's one way: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/5knwv203/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should concatenate the `" \n"` at the end of nested loop

```js
function print(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
    return msg;
}


let result = "";

for(let i=1; i<=8; i++) {
    for(let j=1; j<8; j++) {
        result += " #";
    }
    result += " #\n"
}

print(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is by using arrays:

- Create a new array of 8 elements
- Fill it
- Map each element to 8 "#"
- Join the array using "\n"

```js
let result = Array(8).fill().map(_=>"# ".repeat(8)).join("\n")
console.log(result);
```

Or just using repeats:

```js
let result = ("# ".repeat(8)+"\n").repeat(8);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert \n after the inner for

```js
function print(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
  return msg;
}


let result = "";

for(let i=1; i<=8; i++) {
    
    for(let j=1; j<8; j++) {
        result += " #";
    }
    
    result += " #\n"
}

print(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution may look like this:

```
  for(let i=1; i<=8; i++) {
    result += " #"
    for(let j=1; j<8; j++) {
      result += " #";
    }
    result += "\n";
  }
```